# ¿Cómo hacer un control genérico en ASP.NET MVC con vistas parciales?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una vista que contiene buscadores, los buscadores reciben la busqueda, la ejecutan y guardan en un hidden el `id` para otras funciones. No logro hacer funcionar esto en una parcial `View`, necesito hacer una vista parcial genérica que no reciba un modelo.

Mi vista:

```
@Html.Partial("_Buscador", new ViewDataDictionary{{"Buscador", @Model.Buscador}})
```

Mi parcial `View`:

```
<div class="form-group ">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.palabra)
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.palabra) 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @carlos, bienvenido a la familia de SOes, como nuevo usuario te recomiendo leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask (has preguntado de manera clara y directa, de todas maneras cae bien esa lectura, tú sabes, la ayuda a los nuevos :D ) si estás comenzando con ASP.net MVC, aqui te comparto un webcast de 4 horas 4 minutos 4 segundos donde tratamos de ir paso a paso por todo lo necesario para tener un mayor alcance sobre dicho framework, te comparto el enlace: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Dale con todo el power 2.0! Éxitos y bendiciones :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aconsejaria que no uses el `@Html.Partial` sino que lo cambies a `@Html.Action`.

Al invocar un action podrias pasarle valor para aplicar logica y que esta devuelva la view

[How can I pass parameters to an Action using Html.Action() in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150491/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-an-action-using-html-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

como veras puedes definir un parametro simple en el action y pasarselo desde la view

```
@Html.Action("Controller","Name", new { buscador = @Model.Buscador })
```

Por supuesto el action devolvera la view que estas definiendo

```
public class xxController
{
   public ActionResult Buscador(string buscador)
   {
      //aqui codigo
      return View("_Buscador", model);
   }
}
```